# Reset linux user password with ssh key based access

Tags: passwords, ubuntu

I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is possible, so I wanted to see opinions of security people.

I have a remote nvidia device left with default credentials and someone brute-forced the device and accessed it and changed the passwords in order to use it for bitcoin mining.

As I setup already ssh key authentication I still have access to the device but when I login I can't do much things, I had an idea running a keylogger but I don't have privilege installing some dependencies required by keylogger scripts and using sudo, also looked some privilege escalation vulnerabilities but they are patched such as **CVE-2021-3156**.

Is there anything I can do, knowing that I have just ssh key based access with a non root user, or I should try recovery mode and redirect to bash and setup new password?

```
OS version: Ubuntu 18.04
sudo version: 

$ uname -a
Linux xavier-desktop 4.9.201-tegra #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Feb 19 08:42:04 PST 2021 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you do not have root access? If you don't have root, and you can't boot it in single-user mode, it's not your system anymore. Reinstall / reset to factory defaults / reflash the "ROM".

Comment: You are basically asking of how to escalate from your own limited privileges on the system to full privileges. That's a  common question an attacker faces, who got limited access to the system. In other words: you are asking for help with breaking into a system, which is off-topic. If there would be a generic way it would be pretty bad security. There might be some vulnerabilities in software or setup specific to your system though which would allow such privilege escalation, but there is nothing specific one can point out with basically no information about the system and no access to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is technically probably possible by using some clever scheme for privilege escalation, but it's very unlikely that you will be able to come up with such a scheme if you are not a professional penetration tester. There is a very good reason why there is a hierarchy of privileges in almost any OS in existence and it would be absolutely horrendous security to allow for some easy trick to escalate your user privileges. Your only realistic option would be to wait until another way to escalate privileges is published, if your system doesn't auto-update. But that could take months or years, if there even IS such a vulnerability that would apply to this specific situation.

Another solution would only apply if you have physical access to the device and its BIOS and main drive isn't encrypted - boot from any Linux live CD (or thumb drive, of course) and use chroot and passwd to set a new root password for the installation.

But if you only have remote access and no way to boot from another medium? Nope, sorry. Your system is lost. Reset it and get on with your life. Next time, disable simple password login or use a stronger password.